# Combobox dependientes PHP

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

Estoy trabajando con PHP y tengo un formulario con los campos Establecimiento, Servicio y Sector. Estos 3 son combobox dependientes y el orden es: elegir un establecimiento, después servicio y finalmente sector. Todo funciona bien pero ahora me percate de un problema.
Cuando selecciono un establecimiento que tiene servicio y sector todo bien, pero cuando selecciono un establecimiento que no tiene servicio ni sector me muestra no aplica en el servicio pero no logro que el sector también quede como no aplica y esto provoca que el sector obviamente no muestre información y no me permita guardar. Espero por favor su ayuda u orientación para resolver esto.
Mi código es el siguiente:

//// PARA BUSCAR EL SERVICIO DESPUES DE SELECCIONAR EL ESTABLECIMIENTO/////

```
$query=$db->query("select * from servicio where id_establecimiento=$_GET[establecimiento] and 
estatus = 1 
ORDER BY nombre_servicio ASC");
$servicios = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $servicios[]=$r; }
if(count($servicios)>0)
{
    print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
    foreach ($servicios as $ser) 
    {
        print "<option value='$ser->id'>$ser->nombre_servicio</option>";
    }
}
else
{
print "<option value=''>NO APLICA</option>";
}
```

///// PARA BUSCAR EL SECTOR DESPUES DE SELECCIONAR EL SERVICIO/////

$query=$db->query("select * from sector where id_servicio=$_GET[servicio] and estatus = 1 ORDER BY nombre_sector ASC");

```
$sectores = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $sectores[]=$r; }
if(count($sectores)>0)
{
    print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
    foreach ($sectores as $se) 
    {
        print "<option value='$se->id'>$se->nombre_sector</option>";
    }
}
else
{
print "<option value=''>NO APLICA</option>";
}
```

/////////MI FORMULARIO////////

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="establecimiento" name="establecimiento">
                  <option value="">Selecciona un Campo Formador y/o Campo Clínico </option>
                <?php  foreach ($all_establecimiento as $est): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo (int)$est['id'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $est['name'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select class="form-control" id="servicio" name="servicio" required>
                    <option value="">Servicio donde se requiere la Pasantia</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="sector" name="sector" required>
                  <option value="">Seleccione Sector (SI APLICA)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

/////JAVASCRIPT/////

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#establecimiento").change(function()
  {
        $.get("servicios.php","establecimiento="+$("#establecimiento").val(), function(data){
            $("#servicio").html(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    $("#servicio").change(function()
  {
        $.get("sectores.php","servicio="+$("#servicio").val(), function(data){
            $("#sector").html(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al seleccionar un establecimiento cargas servicios, una vez que cargaste los servicios cargas los sectores de acuerdo al servicio seleccionado. Fijate donde estoy llamando a la función que carga los sectores, tenes que asegurarte que ya se hayan cargado previamente los servicios.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#establecimiento").change(function(){
        cargar_servicios($("#establecimiento").val());
     });

     $("#servicio").change(function(){
       cargar_sectores($("#servicio").val());
     });

  });

 function cargar_servicios(establecimiento){
   $.get("servicios.php","establecimiento="+establecimiento,    function(data){
           $("#servicio").html(data);

           var servicio = $("#servicio").val();
           cargar_sectores(servicio);
       });
 }

 function cargar_sectores(servicio){
   $.get("sectores.php","servicio="+servicio,    function(data){
           $("#sector").html(data);
       });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Probé el codigo y al seleccionar el establecimiento, el servicio queda como actualizandose muchas veces, pero no cumple con lo que necesito, que es cuando un establecimiento no tenga servicio y al quedar el servicio como NO APLICA, que el sector quede de la misma manera.

Comment: testealo ahora habia un detalle que se me paso, asegurate que el sectores.php cuando le llegue el valor de no aplica que usas en servicios te devuelva un NO APLICA