# ¿Cómo definir estos Select dependientes?

Tags: formularios, select, combobox

he hecho un formulario para registro de clientes dentro de un sistema erp, pero dentro de ellos estoy pidiendo el departamento y municipio de donde viene el cliente de la siguiente forma
[image: Formulario de cliente]

Los municipios cambian en funcion del departamento seleccionado, pero al momento de guardarlos me guarda el value:

tal como esta en el codigo:

```
<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                  <label for="departamentoAgregarDatos">DEPARTAMENTO <strong class="text-danger">*</strong></label>
                  <select class="form-control  mayusc text-uppercase" name="departamentoAgregarDatos" id="departamentoAgregarDatos" maxlength="60">
                    <option value="1">Ahuachapán</option>
                    <option value="2">Santa Ana</option>
                    <option value="3">Sonsonate</option>
                    <option value="4">La Libertad</option>
                    <option value="5">Chalatenango</option>
                    <option value="6">Cuscatlán</option>
                    <option value="7">San Salvador</option>
                    <option value="8">La Paz</option>
                    <option value="9">Cabañas</option>
                    <option value="10">San Vicente</option>
                    <option value="11">Usulután</option>
                    <option value="12">San Miguel</option>
                    <option value="13">Morazán</option>
                    <option value="14">La Unión</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Y este es el Jquery que me hace la funcion de llamar los municipios en funcion del departamento:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#departamentoAgregarDatos").on("change", function() {
            $("#departamentoAgregarDatos option:selected").each(function() {
              elegido = $(this).val();
              $.post("../controlador/insertarDatosdepto.php", {
                elegido: elegido
              }, function(data) {
                $("#municipioAgregarDatos").html(data);
              });
            });
          });
        });
```

Si gustan les comparto una parte del codigo que esta dento del archivo: insertarDatosdepto.php

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Combobox dependientes PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/534504/combobox-dependientes-php)

Comment: Realmente no amigo, ya que el colega el problema que tiene es que el tercer campo no se le activa, en mi caso ambos casos funcionan, lo unico es que al gurdar el dato me esta guardando el valor que esta dentro del "value" y no el texto que esta dentro del <option value="1">texto de ejemplo</option>

Comment: No se comprende cual es el problema?, por favor redacta de nuevo tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes editar las veces que sean necesarias

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. Entiendo. Es simple y hay que leer sobre cómo funciona un form.

Cada campo entrega su value y para un select, el value es lo que le dices en el atributo value. Peeero lo que quieres es **el innerHTML** del valor seleccionado. Entonces, no es el `val()`, que obtiene EL VALUE, sino `html()` que obtiene el innerHTML del nodo option seleccionado.

```js
$("#pepito").on("change", function() {
  $("#pepito option:selected").each(function() {
    console.log('innerHTML:' + $(this).html());
  } )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pepito">
  <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">drei</option>
  <option value="4">IV</option>
</select>
```